# JPA query to traverse two @OneToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to traverse two @OneToMany associations to return the results of the JPA query into a Dto via Spring Data Projection.

The simplified data structure looks like:

**Bird**

```
public class Bird {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Sex sex;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "bird")
    private List<HealthCheck> listHealthCheck = new ArrayList<>();
```

**HealthCheck**

```
public class HealthCheck {
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    private Bird bird;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="healthCheck")
    private List<Task> tasks;
    private LocalDateTime checkDateTime;
```

**Task (abstract)**

```
public abstract class Task {
    @Id
    private Long taskId;
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private HealthCheck healthCheck;
```

**LengthMeasurements**

```
public class LengthMeasurements extends Task {    
    private Double beakLength;
    private Double legLength;
```

Each `Bird` has an associated @OneToMany list of `HealthCheck` and `HealthCheck` in turn has a @OneToMany list of LengthMeasurements via Task abstraction.

I would like a JPA query to return data into my `BirdDetailsDto`

```
public class BirdDetailsDto {
    private String name;
    private Sex sex;
    private LengthMeasurements currentLengthMeasurements
```

The JPA query should return bird.name, bird.sex and the *most recent average* LengthMeasurement (based on HealthCheck.checkDateTime) into the `BirdDetailsDto`.

**Q:** Is this possible?

Comment: I think `BirdDetailsDto` is not a DTO, because it includes `LengthMeasurements` that extends the JPA Entity `Task`. Is your example correct?

Comment: Each `HealthCheck` has a number of tasks of different types - like `LengthMeasurments` - I think this is correct?

Comment: If your `Bird` has 5 `HealthChecks`, and each `HealthCheck` has 5 `Tasks` of type `LengthMeasurements`, which would need to used?

Comment: Good point. The newest lengthmeasurement - since HealthCheck can have more than one Lengthmeasurement return the average.

Answer (score 0):

A HQL query like the following should produce the desired results:

```
SELECT NEW com.nz.kiwi.view.BirdDetailsDto(b.name, b.sex, b.status, lm.beakLength, lm.legLength)
FROM Bird b
JOIN (SELECT l.beakLength beakLength, l.legLength legLength FROM b.healthCheck.lengthMeasurements l ORDER BY l.healthCheck.checkDate DESC LIMIT 1) lm
```